# How to run gevent threads in batches without waiting for each batch to finish using Gevent?

Tags: python-3.x, gevent

I have written a program that will make 210 calls, at 4 different stages during my program execution. It's written in python 3.6 and uses gevent (with monkey patch). At each stage it will batch 50 calls then run gevent.joinall() on said threads.

This is a workaround I implemented because I hit a rate-limit of 50 calls/sec. So when I make these calls, I take 50 at a time and batch them (15 sec delay in between, using gevent.sleep(15))

My current workaround:

```
    def func(args, batch_size, batch):
        for i in range(0, len(args), batch_size):
            threads=[]
            for arg in args[i:i+batch_size]: 
                if func.__name__ == 'check_vsi':
                    if 'WIN' in self.history[arg]['order']['os_code']:
                         start_time = time.time()
                        threads.append(gevent.spawn(self.check_vsi, arg, start_time, 1800))
                    else:  wait 15 min
                        start_time = time.time()
                        threads.append(gevent.spawn(self.check_vsi, arg, start_time, 900))
                else:
                    print('Args are {}'.format(args))
                    threads.append(gevent.spawn(func, arg))

            gevent.joinall(threads)
            print('Sleeping for 15 seconds between batches')
            gevent.sleep(15) # sleep 15 seconds between batches
            _ = [results.append(t.value) for t in threads]:
```

One can think of each batch as a **list** of spawned greenlet threads. Is there a way to run each batch (with 15 second delay) then wait for all 210 (5 batches) to finish executing? Or do I need to wait on execution for each batch before starting the next batch?

Please keep in mind I am storing responses from these calls, and responses are carried through the program until the end when I make an update the the db.